# calling key in dataframe returns keyerror

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to retrieve data by using the keys that I assigned when using the concat function, however, it always returns keyerror.

for example:

```
lists = pd.DataFrame({ "no_1": [1,2,3,4]})
x = pd.DataFrame( {"no_2": [3,3,4,5]})
total = pd.concat([lists, x], axis=0, keys=["a", "b"])
print(total["a"])
```

This will return keyerror 'a'. It ought to print the data assigned under the key 'a'.

Comment: Are you really sure of the axis in `pd.concat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `total["a"]` tries to retrieve column `"a"` from the dataframe `total`, while "a" is an index (a row identifier) here.

To select such an index, you need to use `total.loc["a"]` instead.

Comment: oh I see, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to use `axis=1` (columns) instead of `axis=0`  (index) in `pd.concat`:

```
total = pd.concat([lists, x], axis=1, keys=["a", "b"]) 
print(total["a"])

# Output:
   no_1
0     1
1     2
2     3
3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
total.loc[total.index.get_level_values(0) == 'a']
```

Comment: This is the third answer of yours I encounter in the [Low Quality Answers review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Just letting you know so you can improve you current and future answers to avoid down-votes and deletions. Answers having no more than a *"try this: <some code>"* are not very useful and will benefit much more from some explanations of *why* and *how* the code is actually relevant and solves the problem. You can read more about [answer]